# IE7 dynamic content produces no vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, css, ajax, internet-explorer-7

I've got an IE7 issue i need some help with. I'm loading in a table of data via ajax and php. Works fine everywhere except IE7 (doi).

The problem is that there isn't a vertical scrollbar after it loads several hundred records.
I've checked into the position and overflow bugs (like here: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/position_relative_overflow_ie/) but have still had no luck as of yet.

The arrow keys don't work, either. Only way to see what's below the fold of the browser window is to click and drag.

Any help is appreciated.

=================

UPDATE:

Wanted to include some images of what's going on. Can't give access to the page/files, has sensitive information. Hopefully this can help a bit, though.

Before:
[image: before searching]

After:
[image: after searching]

The code for the table goes something like this:

```
<div class="row hide" id="spend-table" style="display: block;"><table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" id="spend">
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="display: none;">Id</th><th>Name</th><th>City</th><th>State</th><th>Vendor</th><th>Catalog#</th><th>Fac#</th><th>Desc</th><th>Quantity</th><th>UOM</th><th>Total</th><th>Highest</th><th>Lowest</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="display: none;">35816</td><td>Boblawblaw</td><td>Law BLog</td><td>KY</td><td>The Avengers</td><td>DE878Z</td><td>12091</td><td>Canned Butterscotch</td><td>1</td><td>YR</td><td>$127.13</td><td>$127.13</td><td>$127.13</td><td style="display: none;">2</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table></div>
```

The table's parent div is hidden initially, but after the search is performed (via AJAX & Codeigniter) the results are kicked back from CI using the Table class to populate the div with the new info (table).

Just to be clear: all the records show up as they ought. You can click and drag to see everything. It's simply an issue of scroll/overflow/etc. getting overlooked in IE7.

Thanks!

===================
Another update:

The table, the table's containing div, and that div's containing div all have heights of 800+. The body, however, is stuck at 348px. Have zoom, position, and overflow attributes set. Out of ideas :\

Comment: try: body, html {position:relative;height:100%}

Comment: no luck there. thanks tho :\

Comment: Tried setting the `overflow-y` on the surrounding `div`?

Comment: yup. tried setting overflows, zooms, positions, etc. on pretty much everything imaginable :\

Comment: silly question, you tried overflow: auto?

Comment: had. was a mixture of adding this back and removing other things that fixed it. about to post.

Comment: Just dropping by to say I like the look and attitude of your project. That is all

Comment: thanks @tuespetre, i appreciate it. if there's one thing we've received validation on thus far it's that witty, fun experience. thanks for further confirmation! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@mikedidthis helped out big time in the chat room.

i had added too many overflows throughout. removed it from the body by changing to `overflow: auto !important;` and removed from the `.container`

the overflow bug fix ended up becoming the bug itself :p thanks for all the help and commentary.

best,